# java get length of List but always got = 1

Tags: java, arraylist

How to get length of list, when I try to println it I just got result =  1, even a value in it list is many.

This is my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<lisPpob.size(); i++){
  // first code
  System.out.println("param 1 = "+ lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T());

  //secount code
  List<String> lis= Arrays.asList(lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T());
  System.out.println("length = " + lis.size());
}
```

in first code I get :

```
param 1 = 986, 5785, 57, 675, 57
```

in the second code I get :

```
length = 1
```

Comment: Perhaps it has one element with the value of `"986, 5765, 57, 675, 57"`.

Comment: You probably want `List<String> lis= Arrays.asList(lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T().split(", "));`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to have a string that you need to split..

```
System.out.println("length = "+ lisPpob.get(i).getLBRAP2T().split(", ").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the output of the first print statement is

```
param 1 = 986, 5785, 57, 675, 57
```

then it means that the return type of `getLBRAP2T()` is a single `String`, not a `Collection`/`List`/`Set` (would have printed `[]`) or a an array (would have printed `xxxx@hhhh`). *(Could also be some object with a `toString()` implementation. You could of course confirm by telling us what the type is.)*

So, when you call `Arrays.asList(string)`, you are creating a **list of one element**: The string. That is because you are only passing a single parameter to `asList()` and that parameter is not a non-primitive array.